# Change model in renderer.listen function in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular5, angular2-changedetection

I have custom drop-down in my application. I need to handle clicks outside the component for hiding drop-down list. I want to make it dynamically.

`HostListener` is not the case, because it adds event listeners for all dropdown components on the page. So i decided to add and remove listener dynamically with `renderer.listener`.
So i have function that fired when user is clicking input element:

```
onClickInput() {
 if (this.isOpened) {
  return this.isOpened = false;
 }
 this.clickOutsideHandler();
}
```

Where `clickOutsideHandler` is:

```
clickOutsideHandler() {
 this.clickOutside = this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (evt) => {
  if (!this.el.nativeElement.contains(evt.target) && this.isOpened) {
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.clickOutside();
  }
 });
}
```

Is it the best solution to use `this.cdRef.detectChanges()`, because angular didn't update the view without it when i change `this.isOpened = false;` in `renderer.listener`. Is there better way to do this?

Comment: have you tried using **EventEmitter**

Comment: What exactly is your suggestion?